# How to handle some strings matching a regular expression?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a table of the form:

```
id, name (text), characteristics (text),
1, 'ivan', 'lier, tall'
2, 'michailmichail', 'gnorts, wol, rtams'
3, 'sergei', 'smart'
```

How to perform the function of processing strings that match the regular expression, so that all the values ​​in the resulting table remain?
Reverse values ​​in the characteristics column if the name in the name is repeated several times!

The resulting table should be:

```
id, name (text), characteristics (text),
1, 'ivan', 'lier, tall'
2, 'michailmichail', 'smart, low, strong'
3, 'sergei', 'smart'
```

This regular expression passes the test but does not work after `WHERE '\b(\w+)+\1\b'`. And I do not know how to process the rows matching re and display all the values ​​of the column.

```
SELECT
  name, reverse(characteristics) as characteristics
FROM
  table
WHERE name ~* 'regexp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a regex here

```
select
    id,
    name,
    case
        when    length(name) % 2 = 0
                and left(name, length(name) / 2) = right(name, length(name) / 2)
        then    reverse(characteristics)
        else    characteristics
    end as characteristics
from
    <table_name>
```

although with a regex it'd be

```
select
    id,
    name,
    case
        when name ~* '^(\w+)\1$'
        then reverse(characteristics)
        else characteristics
    end as characteristics
from
    <table_name>
```

Comment: Please post in English